# How to find the highest value in an array and its position

Tags: java, arrays

So I have an array and I know how to find the highest value but I can't figure out how to obtain the position of that value in the array. The method so far is as follows:

```
 public static void findHottest(int[] temp){
        int hottest = temp[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++){
            if(temp[i] > hottest) {
                hottest = temp[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: So.  All you need to do is add a "position" variable that tracks the index of the "hottest" entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void findHottest(int[] temp){
    int hottest = temp[0];
    int highestIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(temp[i] > hottest) {
            hottest = temp[i];
            highestIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Just store the index when you encounter a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer. In your code

```
    public static void findHottest(int[] temp){
            int hottest = temp[0];
int index =0;
            for(int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++){
                if(temp[i] > hottest) {
                    hottest = temp[i]; 
                    index =i // index is the index you are looking for.
                }
            }
```

So, just have an `index` variable that gets updated whenever `hottest = temp[i]` statement gets executed.